# How to check if in gzip file in Snowflake stage, any file is 0B?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to check from Snowflake level if in Snowflake Stage, gzip file contains 0B file[s]?

As i know 'list' function will return gzip file size in stage.

But how to find out if in gzip file is file of size 0B?